# How to create an integer array in Python?

Tags: python, arrays

It should not be so hard. I mean in C,

```
int a[10];
```

is all you need. How to create an array of all zeros for a random size. I know the zeros() function in NumPy but there must be an easy way built-in, not another module.

Comment: Python doesn't have a built-in array data structure. The closest you get to that are lists.

Comment: Surprisingly, nobody has actually asked what you need this for.  Usually lists are just fine, regardless of the fact that you could store other stuff in them (they're just lists of references to other objects, which can be anything).  But maybe there's some reason that wouldn't work well for you...

Comment: I highly recommend the Python tutorial: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/ It'll only take a couple hours of your time.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

If you are not satisfied with lists (because they can contain anything and take up too much memory) you can use efficient array of integers:

```
import array
array.array('i')
```

See [here](http://docs.python.org/library/array.html)

If you need to initialize it,

```
a = array.array('i',(0 for i in range(0,10)))
```

Comment: This will initialize an array with 9 elements, not 10

Comment: This seems to be the most efficient way.

Comment: Sorry, but I tried that also. Although it is the most reasonable way, it gets weird with the initialization part which requires a 'list'.

Comment: it's a generator expression, so it's won't cost memory for very large arrays, but I agree that it is inefficient compared to `memset` or so.

Comment: It's Python ffs, memset and C-level efficiency are not a concern.

Answer (score 33):

two ways:

```
x = [0] * 10
x = [0 for i in xrange(10)]
```

Edit: replaced `range` by `xrange` to avoid creating another list.

Also: as many others have noted including Pi and Ben James, this creates a `list`, not a Python array. While a list is in many cases sufficient and easy enough, for performance critical uses (e.g. when duplicated in thousands of objects) you could look into python arrays. Look up the `array` module, as explained in the other answers in this thread.

Comment: This is a list. It can contain objects of any type, not just integers. And it uses much more RAM than needed for integers.

Comment: Not only that, range returns a list too. So the second line will at least use twice the memory of the resulting list.

Comment: Be careful when multiplying lists -- it will give you trouble with mutable objects. Multiplication doesn't clone items, but merely gives you the very same object appearing multiple times in a list. Try this: `a = [[1]]*3; a[1].append(2)`. Therefore, appending to `a[1]` will really change all the items of a and give you `[[1,2],[1,2],[1,2]]`.

Comment: and replace `xrange` back to `range` in py3k

Comment: Sure, but i find these lines more readable then using the array module, for example. For 10 integers I wouldn't be too concerned about memory either (in most cases). Besides, the question was "an easy way built-in, no another module".

Comment: +1. One can contrive of corner cases where these don't apply, but your answers are the natural, pythonic solutions to the question.

Answer (score 11):

```
>>> a = [0] * 10
>>> a
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 6):

Use the *array* module. With it you can store collections of the same type efficiently.

```
>>> import array
>>> import itertools
>>> a = array_of_signed_ints = array.array("i", itertools.repeat(0, 10))
```

For more information - e.g. different types, look at [the documentation of the array module](http://docs.python.org/library/array.html). For up to 1 million entries this should feel pretty snappy. For 10 million entries my local machine thinks for 1.5 seconds.

The second parameter to *array.array* is a *generator*, which constructs the defined sequence as it is read. This way, the array module can consume the zeros one-by-one, but the generator only uses constant memory. This generator does not get bigger (memory-wise) if the sequence gets longer. The array will grow of course, but that should be obvious.

You use it just like a list:

```
>>> a.append(1)
>>> a.extend([1, 2, 3])
>>> a[-4:]
array('i', [1, 1, 2, 3])
>>> len(a)
14
```

...or simply convert it to a list:

```
>>> l = list(a)
>>> len(l)
14
```

Surprisingly

```
>>> a = [0] * 10000000
```

is faster at construction than the array method. Go figure! :)

Answer (score 3):

```
import numpy as np

new_array=np.linspace(0,10,11).astype('int')
```

An alternative for casting the type when the array is made.

Answer (score 2):

```
a = 10 * [0]
```

gives you an array of length 10, filled with zeroes.

Comment: This is not called an array in Python, it is a list

Comment: I believe the questioner took the "array" terminology from C, and looks for a close built-in alternative in Python. In a lot of cases, one would just use a list in Python.

Comment: catchmeifyoutry: I would still let the questioner know the correct terminology for what they are using, no matter what the C alternative is

Comment: questioner knows the difference. That's why he insists using the 'array'. Thanks for anonymously talking about me. :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
import random

def random_zeroes(max_size):
  "Create a list of zeros for a random size (up to max_size)."
  a = []
  for i in xrange(random.randrange(max_size)):
    a += [0]
```

Use `range` instead if you are using Python 3.x.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to initialize an array fast, you might do it by blocks instead of with a generator initializer, and it's going to be much faster. Creating a list by `[0]*count` is just as fast, still.

```
import array

def zerofill(arr, count):
    count *= arr.itemsize
    blocksize = 1024
    blocks, rest = divmod(count, blocksize)
    for _ in xrange(blocks):
        arr.fromstring("\x00"*blocksize)
    arr.fromstring("\x00"*rest)

def test_zerofill(count):
    iarr = array.array('i')
    zerofill(iarr, count)
    assert len(iarr) == count

def test_generator(count):
    iarr = array.array('i', (0 for _ in xrange(count)))
    assert len(iarr) == count

def test_list(count):
    L = [0]*count
    assert len(L) == count

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import timeit
    c = 100000
    n = 10
    print timeit.Timer("test(c)", "from __main__ import c, test_zerofill as test").repeat(number=n)
    print timeit.Timer("test(c)", "from __main__ import c, test_generator as test").repeat(number=n)
    print timeit.Timer("test(c)", "from __main__ import c, test_list as test").repeat(number=n)
```

Results:

```
(array in blocks) [0.022809982299804688, 0.014942169189453125, 0.014089107513427734]
(array with generator) [1.1884641647338867, 1.1728270053863525, 1.1622772216796875]
(list) [0.023866891860961914, 0.035660028457641602, 0.023386955261230469]
```

Comment: interesting, python really optimizes initialization. I get on ubuntu 9.04, python 2.6.2 (I truncated the output a little):

    (array in blocks) [0.0191, 0.0180, 0.0170]
    (array with generator) [0.9199, 0.9179, 0.6761]
    (list) [0.0069, 0.0074, 0.0064]

so on my machine lists are significantly faster. kaizer.se, what OS/python are you running?

Comment: This was from my venerable iBook, a laptop 5 years of age w PowerPC G4 running Debian/Linux, of course. No doubt there are faster machines around :-)

Comment: My point is not to compare our machines, but to compare the time differences on the machines. Your results show more or less (array in blocks) in the same order of speed as (list), while on my machine (or python implementation) the (list) method is a factor faster.

Comment: Oh, how dumb of me, forgot some information like that it was using Python 2.5.4 on Debian. Testing shows no difference across Python 2.6 to Python2.5 here.

Comment: The fastest array initialization is `array.array('i', [0]) * count` because it can allocate the exact memory size directly without reallocation and without a big temporary list. see http://stackoverflow.com/a/3216322/448474