# how to make a python array of particular objects

Tags: python, arrays, types

in java, the following code defines an array of the predefined class (`myCls`):

```
myCls arr[] = new myCls
```

how can I do that in python? I want to have an array of type (`myCls`)?

thanks in advance

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1924469/define-a-list-with-type

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Python is dynamically typed. You do not need to (and in fact CAN'T) create a list that only contains a single type:

```
arr = list()
arr = []
```

If you require it to only contain a single type then you'll have to create your own list-alike, reimplementing the list methods and `__setitem__()` yourself.

Comment: but you CAN create arrays of only integers, double, etc. types in python

Comment: I don't think that the OP cares about the difference between arrays and lists.

Comment: The statement that you cannot is false, however.

Comment: No, it isn't. list does not care what class it contains. Yes, you can create a list-alike that only accepts a single type, or use array.array, but neither of those is a list.

Comment: @Ignacio: indeed your "CAN'T" statement as specified is false. In python, you CAN create a list that contains items of a single type; what you can't, is you CAN'T ENFORCE the list items to be of a single type.

Answer (score 5):

You can only create arrays of only a single type using the [array](http://docs.python.org/library/array.html) package, but it is not designed to store user-defined classes.

The python way would be to just create a list of objects:

```
a = [myCls() for _ in xrange(10)]
```

You might want to take a look at [this stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1859864/how-to-create-an-integer-array-in-python/1859887#1859887) question.

**NOTE:**

Be careful with this notation, IT PROBABLY DOES NOT WHAT YOU INTEND:

```
a = [myCls()] * 10
```

This will also create a list with ten times a myCls object, but it is ten times THE SAME OBJECT, not ten independently created objects.