# What is the fastest way to initialize an integer array in python?

Tags: python, arrays, integer

Say I wanted to create an array (NOT list) of 1,000,000 twos in python, like this:

`array = [2, 2, 2, ...... , 2]`

What would be a fast but simple way of doing it?

Comment: I know practically no Python, but could it be something like `array = [2 for x in 1..1000000]`?

Comment: This previous question might help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1859864/how-to-create-an-integer-array-in-python

Comment: @mmyers: Your suggestion is not valid syntax; you possibly mean `[2 for x in xrange(1000000)]`; `[2] * 1000000` would be faster and simpler; however these produce a `list` -- `array` and `list` mean different things in Python.

Comment: @John: mmyers had said he doesn't practically know python. so stop nitpicking :) Ofcourse appreciate the suggestions.

Comment: @Vijay Dev: Please stop conflating "educating" and "nitpicking". If @mmyers were to ask a question, I'd be glad to supply references to manuals and tutorials. Who appreciates what suggestions??

Comment: @John: Thanks. I figured I could get better by posting what I would think and having people correct me. (Now I wonder where I got the `1..1000000` from. Probably Ruby.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NumPy array initialization (fill with identical values)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891410/numpy-array-initialization-fill-with-identical-values)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Is this what you're after?

```
# slower.
twosArr = array.array('i', [2] * 1000000)

# faster.
twosArr = array.array('i', [2]) * 1000000
```

You can get just a list with this:

```
twosList = [2] * 1000000
```

-- EDITED --

I updated this to reflect information in another answer.  It would appear that you can increase the speed by a ratio of ~ 9 : 1 by adjusting the syntax slightly.  Full credit belongs to @john-machin.  I wasn't aware you could multiple the array object the same way you could do to a list.

Answer (score 18):

The currently-accepted answer is NOT the fastest way using `array.array`; at least it's not the slowest -- compare these:

```
[source: johncatfish (quoting chauncey), Bartek]
python -m timeit -s"import array" "arr = array.array('i', (2 for i in range(0,1000000)))"
10 loops, best of 3: 543 msec per loop

[source: g.d.d.c]
python -m timeit -s"import array" "arr = array.array('i', [2] * 1000000)"
10 loops, best of 3: 141 msec per loop

python -m timeit -s"import array" "arr = array.array('i', [2]) * 1000000"
100 loops, best of 3: 15.7 msec per loop
```

That's a ratio of about 9 to 1 ...

Comment: +1 and I've updated my answer with the other syntax and a comment.  Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: slooow :) ... hybrid of those two version is better

Answer (score 5):

A hybrid approach works fastest for me

```
$ python -m timeit -s"import array" "arr = array.array('i', [2]*100) * 10000"
100 loops, best of 3: 5.38 msec per loop
```

---

```
$ python -m timeit -s"import array" "arr = array.array('i', [2]) * 1000000"
10 loops, best of 3: 20.3 msec per loop
$ python -m timeit -s"import array" "arr = array.array('i', [2]*10) * 100000"
100 loops, best of 3: 6.69 msec per loop
$ python -m timeit -s"import array" "arr = array.array('i', [2]*100) * 10000"
100 loops, best of 3: 5.38 msec per loop
$ python -m timeit -s"import array" "arr = array.array('i', [2]*1000) * 1000"
100 loops, best of 3: 5.47 msec per loop
$ python -m timeit -s"import array" "arr = array.array('i', [2]*10000) * 100"
100 loops, best of 3: 6.13 msec per loop
$ python -m timeit -s"import array" "arr = array.array('i', [2]*100000) * 10"
10 loops, best of 3: 14.9 msec per loop
$ python -m timeit -s"import array" "arr = array.array('i', [2]*1000000)"
10 loops, best of 3: 77.7 msec per loop
```

Answer (score 3):

Using the [timeit](http://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html) module you can kind of figure out what the *fastest* of doing this is:

First off, putting that many digits in a list will kill your machine most likely as it will store it in memory.

However, you can test the execution using something like so. It ran on my computer for a long time before I just gave up, but I'm on an older PC:

```
timeit.Timer('[2] * 1000000').timeit()
```

Ther other option you can look into is using the [array](http://docs.python.org/library/array.html) module which is as stated, `efficient arrays of numeric values`

```
array.array('i', (2 for i in range(0, 1000000)))
```

I did not test the completion time of both but I'm sure the `array` module, which is designed for number sets will be faster.

Edit: Even more fun, you could take a look at [numpy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/) which actually seems to have the fastest execution:

```
from numpy import *
array( [2 for i in range(0, 1000000)])
```

Even faster from the comments:

```
a = 2 * ones(10000000)
```

Awesome!

Comment: Numpy also has dedicated factory functions: `a = 2 * ones(1000000)`

Comment: @Philipp: That's awesome! This is why I love SO. Curiosity to answer a question leads to many learnings for myself. Cheers :-)

Comment: If you can't fit a million-element list or array into your machine's memory, it's dead already. Also, I don't understand "It ran on my computer for a long time" ... see my answer for (a) how to do simple timing using `timeit` at the command prompt (b) how small the measured times (milliseconds!) are (4-year-old laptop running Win XP SP2)

Answer (score 1):

```
aList = [2 for x in range(1000000)]
```

or base on chauncey link

```
anArray =array.array('i', (2 for i in range(0,1000000)))
```

Answer (score 1):

If the initial value doesn't have to be non-zero and if you have /dev/zero available on your platform, the following is about 4.7 times faster than the array('L',[0])*size solution:

```
myarray = array.array('L')
f = open('/dev/zero', 'rb')
myarray.fromfile(f, size)
f.close()
```

In question [How to initialise an integer array.array object with zeros in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37362169/how-to-initialise-an-integer-array-array-object-with-zeros-in-python) I'm looking for a better way.