# Numpy array, fill empty values for a single column

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array in numpy, which was generated using np.array() from a python list so my entries are strings, but some of the values are blank. Here is an example array:

```
['1', '1', '1', '1']
['1', '1', '', '1']
['1', '1', '1', '1']
['1', '', '1', '1']
```

There is no 'NaN' or 'None', it is blank. I want to be able to fill all the blank cells in a particular column with the same value.

Comment: possible duplicate of [numpy array initialization (fill with identical values)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891410/numpy-array-initialization-fill-with-identical-values)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `numpy.where()` to achieve this.

```
In [8]: arr = numpy.array(['','1','2','3',''])

In [9]: arr[numpy.where(arr=='')] = '0'

In [10]: arr
Out[10]:
array(['0', '1', '2', '3', '0'],
      dtype='|S1')
```

*Edit* As @mgilson pointed out, you could just do:

```
arr[arr==''] = '0'
```

Comment: I don't think `np.where` is necessary here (is it?).  can't you just do `arr[arr==''] = '0'`?

Comment: I want to fill the blank cells of a particular column, not all blank cells. Say I use the code: arr[arr[0::,1]==''] = '0'. This turns any row with a blank in the 2nd column into all 0 entries, not just the blank.

Comment: You need to index the first `data` as well. Try: `data[:,1][data[:,1]==''] = '0'`

Comment: Awesome, that worked. Thank you, I tried using numpy.where() before but didn't use the index.