# Fastest way to create an array in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I want to create a 3D array in Python, filled with -1.

I tested these methods:

```
import numpy as np
l = 200
b = 100
h = 30

%timeit grid = [[[-1 for x in range(l)] for y in range(b)] for z in range(h)]
1 loops, best of 3: 458 ms per loop

%timeit grid = -1 * np.ones((l, b, h), dtype=np.int)
10 loops, best of 3: 35.5 ms per loop

%timeit grid = np.zeros((l, b, h), dtype=np.int) - 1
10 loops, best of 3: 31.7 ms per loop

%timeit grid = -1.0 * np.ones((l, b, h), dtype=np.float32)
10 loops, best of 3: 42.1 ms per loop

%%timeit
grid = np.empty((l,b,h))
grid.fill(-1.0)
100 loops, best of 3: 13.7 ms per loop
```

So obviously, the last one is the fastest. Does anybody has an even faster method or at least less memory intensive? Because it runs on a RaspberryPi.

Comment: I think the most common way to create such an array is: `grid = np.full((l, b, h), -1)`. Not faster though.

Comment: Oh, I saw, my question is a dup of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891410/numpy-array-initialization-fill-with-identical-values).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing I can think to add is that any of these methods will be faster with the `dtype` argument chosen to take up as little memory as possible.

Assuming you need no more space that `int8`, the method suggested by @RutgerKassies in the comments took this long on my system:

```
%timeit grid = np.full((l, b, h), -1, dtype=np.int8)
1000 loops, best of 3: 286 µs per loop
```

For comparison, not specifying `dtype` (defaulting to `int32`) took about 10 times longer with the same method:

```
%timeit grid = np.full((l, b, h), -1)
100 loops, best of 3: 3.61 ms per loop
```

Your fastest method was about as fast as `np.full` (sometimes beating it):

```
%%timeit
grid = np.empty((l,b,h))
grid.fill(-1)
100 loops, best of 3: 3.51 ms per loop
```

or, with `dtype` specified as `int8`,

```
1000 loops, best of 3: 255 µs per loop
```

**Edit**: This is probably cheating, but, well...

```
%timeit grid = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(np.array(-1, dtype=np.int8), (l, b, h), (0, 0, 0))
100000 loops, best of 3: 12.4 us per loop
```

All that's happening here is that we begin with an array of length one, `np.array([-1])`, and then fiddle with the stride lengths so  that `grid` *looks* exactly like an array with the required dimensions.

If you need an actual array, you can use `grid = grid.copy()`; this makes the creation of the `grid` array about as fast as the quickest approaches suggested on elsewhere this page.

Comment: Looking at the code for `np.full` - it creates an `empty`, and uses `copyto` broadcast the value to array.  `x[:]=...` quite possibly uses the same underlying C code.

Answer (score 0):

This is a little faster for me. Might be different on a RPi though.

```
grid = np.empty((l,b,h))
grid[...] = -1
```

`np.int8` is much faster if it's big enough for you

```
grid = np.empty((l,b,h), dtype=np.int8)
grid[...] = -1

%%timeit 
grid = np.empty((l,b,h), dtype=np.int8)
grid[:] = -1 
100 loops, best of 3: 6.91 ms per loop
```

Comment: ```%%timeit
grid = np.empty((l,b,h), dtype=np.int8)
grid[:] = -1
100 loops, best of 3: 6.91 ms per loop```