# Python arrays in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, indexing

I have array:

```
somearray = np.array([])
```

I want to set array on position 10 to have `True` value

```
somearray[10]= True
```

I want to add on spot 10, and I wish that spots 0-9 would be filled with nothing. How can I do this, without index being out of bounds?

Comment: *filled with nothing* is a paradox, unless you're in Seinfeld world.

Comment: But *why*? Do you consider `None` to be "nothing"?

Comment: Some ideas about NumPy array initialization could be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891410/numpy-array-initialization-fill-with-identical-values)

Comment: Javascript can grow arrays like that.  Python lists and numpy arrays can't.

Comment: @hpaulj I was used to Javascript, and I have no idea how to make the same solution in python.

Comment: @speznaz I don't know how big this array will be, so should I just make HUUUUUUUGGGGEEEE one?

Comment: @KamilSeptioTrojnar If you don't know you bounds, there is always a chance for a "out of bound" exception. I think you should explain your problem in a wider context. Arrays probably aren't the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the closest thing in Python to this Javascript array behavior is a dictionary.  It's a hashed mapping.

`defaultdict` is a dictionary that implements a default value.

```
In [1]: from collections import defaultdict
In [2]: arr = defaultdict(bool)
```

Insert a couple of `True` elements:

```
In [3]: arr[10] = True
In [4]: arr
Out[4]: defaultdict(bool, {10: True})
In [5]: arr[20] = True
In [6]: arr
Out[6]: defaultdict(bool, {10: True, 20: True})
```

Fetching some other element returns the `default` (`False` in this case), and adds it to the dictionary:

```
In [7]: arr[3]
Out[7]: False
In [8]: arr
Out[8]: defaultdict(bool, {3: False, 10: True, 20: True})
```

`defaultdict(list)` is a handy way of collecting values in lists within the dictionary.  `defaultdict(int)` implements a counter.

`numpy` arrays have a fixed size, and specified `dtype`:

```
In [21]: x = np.zeros(8, bool)
In [22]: x[5]=True
In [23]: x
Out[23]: array([False, False, False, False, False,  True, False, False])
```

You can make a new array by concatenating with something else (forget the `np.append` function).

Python lists can be initialed to a empty size, `alist= []`, and can grow with `append` or `extend`.  But you can't grow the list by indexing.

Answer (score 0):

If your nothing means null or nan, you can try the below code (reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20606278/9584980)

```
import numpy as np
size = 20
somearray = np.full([size,],np.nan)
somearray[10] = True # but this would make the element to 1. as nans are considered as float. you can change np.nan to False if you literally want a True here
```

EDITED:

If you need to use numpy methods only at the end, you can just store all the required indices and later create a numpy array of the desired size and populate the Trues accordingly.

One more way is to first declare a numpy array of the size as the index that you need (10 in your example). And later resize it if the next index you need to populate is bigger than the array.

```
index = 10
somearray = np.full([index+1,], False)
somearray[index] = True

#if the next index you need to make true is 20 then
index = 20
somearray.resize([index+1,], refcheck=False)
somearray[index] = True
```

Comment: Problem is I don't know what size of an array I do need.

Comment: Edited my earlier answer. Check if that helps