# Creating a np.void object of mixed data type, to use in np.full

Tags: python, numpy

I want to make an array that is filled with a particular value. For simple data types, I can do this with `np.full`. For example, the following code will generate an array of length 10, where each value is the 64-bit integer 10:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.full((10,), -1, np.int64)
```

But I have more complicated, mixed, array data types. For example, I'd *expect* the following code to work:

```
import numpy as np
data_type = [("value_1", np.int64), ("value_2", np.float64)]
default = (-1, np.nan)
arr = np.full((10,), default, data_type)
```

This gives `ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (2) into shape (10)`. I know why (it tries putting each value of my default into a separate element of my array) - it just isn't what I want it to do (putting my *entire* default into each element of the array.

I'd be able to get around this by making my default something that numpy recognizes to be a single element. For example, this works:

```
default_array = np.array([default], data_type)
new_default = default_array[0]
arr = np.full((10,), new_default, data_type)
```

But this is sure to confuse any future readers of my code, myself included.

Now on to my actual question:
Is there any way to make this `new_default` object without going through the hoop of first creating an array?

The `new_default` object is of type `numpy.void`, but I can't seem to create my own such object through, e.g. `np.void(default)`.

Comment: look at the python code `np.full`

Answer (score 1):

The short answer - don't use `np.full` to construct a structured array.  Make the blank array, and assign the value with `arr[:] = default_tuple`.

---

It's the `copyto` that's have problems broadcasting the default:

```
In [596]: np.full(3,default)                                                         
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py in full(shape, fill_value, dtype, order)
    334         dtype = array(fill_value).dtype
    335     a = empty(shape, dtype, order)
--> 336     multiarray.copyto(a, fill_value, casting='unsafe')
    337     return a
    338 

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (2) into shape (3)
```

Evidently `copyto` takes the `fill_value`, converts it to an array (`input array from shape (2)`) , and attempts to broadcast it to the target.

```
In [599]: np.array(default)                                                          
Out[599]: array([-1., nan])
```

---

But indexed assignment takes the tuple default just fine:

```
In [589]: arr = np.zeros(3, dtype=data_type)                                         
In [590]: arr[:] = default                                                           
In [591]: arr                                                                        
Out[591]: 
array([(-1, nan), (-1, nan), (-1, nan)],
      dtype=[('value_1', '<i8'), ('value_2', '<f8')])
```

This passes the tuple to `arr` unchanged. Default data input to a structured array is a list of tuples,

```
In [600]: np.array([default,default,default], dtype=data_type)                       
Out[600]: 
array([(-1, nan), (-1, nan), (-1, nan)],
      dtype=[('value_1', '<i8'), ('value_2', '<f8')])
```

---

Yes, the `type` of an element of a structured array is `np.void`, but as far as I know, `np.void` can't be used as an object constructor.  There's no such documentation, and my experiments have failed.

But then, `np.float32(23)`, while it works, isn't good numpy practice.  I see it more often in beginners code than in numpy functions.

To me, making a single element structured array is perfectly normal:

```
In [573]: x=np.array(default, dtype=data_type)                                       
In [574]: x                                                                          
Out[574]: array((-1, nan), dtype=[('value_1', '<i8'), ('value_2', '<f8')])
In [575]: type(x[()])                                                                
Out[575]: numpy.void
In [576]: x.item()                                                                   
Out[576]: (-1, nan)

In [577]: np.full(3, x)      # full can deduce dtype from fill_value                                                            
Out[577]: 
array([(-1, nan), (-1, nan), (-1, nan)],
      dtype=[('value_1', '<i8'), ('value_2', '<f8')])
```

Concatenation requires the same thing - creating an object of matching dtype

```
In [583]: np.hstack((arr,default))                                                   
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError: invalid type promotion

In [584]: np.hstack((arr,x))                                                         
Out[584]: 
array([(-1, nan), (-1, nan), (-1, nan), (-1, nan)],
      dtype=[('value_1', '<i8'), ('value_2', '<f8')])
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that `np.full` can handle more than one default; [the documentation states](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.full.html): "fill_value : scalar". I think you're better off by creating two separate arrays and merging them afterwards.

You can, however, pass the various dtypes, to get at least that part in one go, e.g.:

```
arr=np.full(10,-1,'|S4, (2,1)i4, f8')
```

or

```
dts=np.dtype([('f1', np.int64), ('f2', np.float64)])
arr=np.full(10,-1,dts)
```

[See here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html#arrays-dtypes) for the relevant documentation, also have a look at this [general discussion on performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891410).