# Create 3d np array with tuple elements

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I want to create a 3-D `np.array` of dimensions `(100x100x100)` with the tuple `(-1,-1,-1)` for every element. Is there a faster/better way than:

```
np.array([[[(0,0,0) for x in range(100)] for y in range(100)] for z in range(100)])
```

?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NumPy array initialization (fill with identical values)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891410/numpy-array-initialization-fill-with-identical-values)

Comment: Explain why you need an array with tuple elements.  That's not an optimal array computaitonally.  Also tell us about the array your code produced.  What's its `shape` and `dtype`.  Is that really an array of tuples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see the shape of your array is actually `(100, 100, 100, 3)`

```
>>> np.array([[[(0,0,0) for x in range(100)] for y in range(100)] for z in range(100)]).shape
(100, 100, 100, 3)
```

You can uses the `np.full` function to generate the desired array.

```
np.full([100, 100, 100, 3], -1)
```

This creates a 100x100x100x3 numpy array, which has an equivalent structure to yours as required.

```
>>> (np.array([[[(0,0,0) for x in range(100)] for y in range(100)] for z in range(100)]) == np.full([100, 100, 100, 3], 0)).all()
True
```

Documentation for [`np.full()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.full.html#numpy.full)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not really creating a (100x100x100) array.

Maybe you can try:

```
np.ones((100, 100, 100))*-1
```

Comment: This is not the shape that the OP is after, their array has shape (100, 100, 100, 3)