# Create a vector length n with n entries 'x'

Tags: python, numpy, vector

**Example:**

```
n = 5
x = 3.5
Output:
array([3.5, 3.5, 3.5, 3.5, 3.5])
```

**My code:**

```
import numpy as np
def init_all_x(n, x):
    np.all = [x]*n
    return np.all
init_all_x(5, 3.5)
```

**My question:**

Why init_all_x(5, 3.5).shape cannot run?

If my code is wrong, what is the correct code?
Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NumPy array initialization (fill with identical values)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891410/numpy-array-initialization-fill-with-identical-values)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use np.ones

```
arr = np.ones(5)*3.5
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple approach with [`numpy.repeat`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html):

```
n = 5
x = 3.5
a = np.repeat(x, n)
```

Output:

```
array([3.5, 3.5, 3.5, 3.5, 3.5])
```

Answer (score 0):

For your requirement, no need to use `Numpy lib`, you can code like this:

```
def init_all_x(n, x):
    return [x]*n

p = init_all_x(5, 3.5)
print(p)
```

Output:

```
[3.5, 3.5, 3.5, 3.5, 3.5]
```

Answer (score 0):

Numpy has a dedicated function [`np.full`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.full.html) to do just this:

```
n = 5
x = 3.5

out = np.full(n, x)
# array([3.5, 3.5, 3.5, 3.5, 3.5])
```